# Error instalando SQL Server: el paquete requerido SqlSupport.msi no existe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Estoy instalando SQL Server 2017, pero cuando llega al paso de listo para instalar (*Ready to Install*), recibo el [siguiente problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rnfP.jpg):

> Error: The required MSI package 'C:\Developer\Dev\2058_ESM_LP\x64\setup\SqlSupport.msi' doesn't exist.

No sé cómo solucionar este error, no sé lo que es un MSI y que debería de hacer. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema e instalar SQL Server 2017?

Comment: revisa la sig. url: https://support.microsoft.com/es-us/help/969052/how-to-restore-the-missing-windows-installer-cache-files-and-resolve-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te falta es el paquete que contiene los archivos faltantes en el siguiente link encontraras informacion

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/955504/the-repair-process-for-the-setup-support-files-may-fail-when-you-try-t

Comment: Hola Bruno Sosa Fast Tag, sería ideal que incluyeras las partes clave de ese enlace en la respuesta en sí (especialmente los pasos para resolver el problema). De ese modo, si el enlace se rompe o cambia, entonces la respuesta seguirá teniendo sentido. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó con SQL 2016, y el problema era que tenía instalado SQL2017 en Inglés y mi instalador era en ESP, los pasos para solucionarlo deberían ser:

- Cambiar el idioma del Windows a a la del ISO
- Si no desea cambiar el idioma descomprime el ISO y copia la carpeta "3082_ESN_LP" y renombrala por "1033_ENU_LP"
- Volver a ejecutar el instalador de SQL y así cuando el vuelva a buscar este file lo encontrará.

A mí me funcionó

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes que cambiar el idioma a español españa y reiniciar tu pc para que se modifique asi ya te dejara instalar